# Retrieving records from a has_many :through relationship, including join model columns and given a constraint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've set up three models: User, List, and UserList -- the latter being the join model between User and List, in a has_many_through relationship.

The UserList "join model" also has a column called "rating".

I'd like to retrieve all "List" records for a given user, plus the ratings for each List record from UserList. However, I'm doing something wrong and have been going round in circles a bit. Would appreciate guidance on what I'm not understanding.

### Technical details

Here are the three models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_lists
  has_many :lists, through: :user_lists, dependent: :destroy
End

class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_lists
  has_many :users, through: :user_lists, dependent: :destroy

  # no duplicate titles in the List table
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
End

class UserList < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :user

  # a given user can only have one copy of a list item
  validates :list_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end
```

### Desired outcome

Retrieve all (and only) List items that belong to the current user, plus each List item's rating from the UserList model.

### My code so far

```
# list_controller.rb

def index
  @lists = current_user
    .lists
    .joins(:user_lists)
    .select('lists.*, user_lists.id as user_lists_id, user_lists.rating as rating')
    .order(:id)
  render json: @lists
end
```

I hacked the above together from various Stack Overflow articles. But it's not quite correct and I'm not sure why.

Here's the rails console output when the controller index code is run:

```
List Load (1.2ms)
  SELECT DISTINCT
    lists.*,
    user_lists.id as user_lists_id,
    user_lists.rating as rating
  FROM "lists"
  INNER JOIN "user_lists" "user_lists_lists"
    ON "user_lists_lists"."list_id" = "lists"."id"
  INNER JOIN "user_lists"
    ON "lists"."id" = "user_lists"."list_id"
  WHERE "user_lists"."user_id" = $1
  ORDER BY "lists"."id" ASC  [["user_id", 1]]

[#<List:0x00007fef741da338
  id: 2,
  title: "useronly",
  created_at: Sat, 09 Feb 2019 09:22:44 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sat, 09 Feb 2019 09:22:44 UTC +00:00>,
 #<List:0x00007fef741d9f78
  id: 3,
  title: "The Art of Gathering",
  created_at: Sat, 09 Feb 2019 09:23:05 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Sat, 09 Feb 2019 09:23:05 UTC +00:00>]
```

The List items are being retrieved correctly -- i.e. the id, title, created_at & updated_at. And, for the current_user only (i.e. not another user's items). **However, the rating column from user_lists is not being retrieved correctly.**

This part of the rails console output doesn't look right at all:

```
  INNER JOIN "user_lists" "user_lists_lists"
    ON "user_lists_lists"."list_id" = "lists"."id"
```

But frankly, I'm not sure how to fix it. I've tried various incantations based on Googling + Stack-Overflowing, but nothing is hitting the mark.

Any ideas? Thanks very much.

### EDITS based on suggestion from Obermillerk:

Based on the `delegate` guidance from Obermillerk, I think that in order to add "title" from the List model to each "user_list" item, I would need to do something like the following:

```
# lists_controller.rb (lines 9 + 11 indicated below)
    def index
      lists = current_user.user_lists
9:       lists.each do |list|
        # retrieve title to each record in user_list. Title is delegated to List
11:         list.title = list.title
      end
      render json: lists
    end
```

However, that's not quite working -- view is empty; server console shows:

```
00:01:22 api.1  |   UserList Load (2.2ms)  SELECT "user_lists".* FROM "user_lists" WHERE "user_lists"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
00:01:22 api.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/lists_controller.rb:9
00:01:22 api.1  |   User Update (1.5ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_login" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["last_login", "2019-02-12 08:01:22.664620"], ["updated_at", "2019-02-12 08:01:22.676667"], ["id", 1]]
00:01:22 api.1  |   ↳ app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:44
00:01:22 api.1  |   List Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
00:01:22 api.1  |   ↳ app/models/user_list.rb:6
00:01:22 api.1  | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 55ms (ActiveRecord: 11.1ms)
00:01:22 api.1  | 
00:01:22 api.1  | 
00:01:22 api.1  |   
00:01:22 api.1  | NoMethodError (undefined method `title=' for #<UserList:0x00007f9220002b48>
00:01:22 api.1  | Did you mean?  title):
00:01:22 api.1  |   
00:01:22 api.1  | app/controllers/api/v1/lists_controller.rb:11:in `block in index'
00:01:22 api.1  | app/controllers/api/v1/lists_controller.rb:9:in `index'
```

Comment: The weird part of the query you pointed out seems to be joining user_lists again, but aliasing it under the name `user_lists_lists`. I believe this comes as a result of the `has_many :through` relationship, it's joining them to find the appropriate lists, and then you also joined with the same table so one of them needs to have a different name to make them unique.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your script, everything is working perfectly. I did not found the issue which you mention in your question. Following is result when I run this index action. You can notice the rating at the end.

```
[{"id":3,"title":"This is list","created_at":"2019-02-09T16:19:18.552Z","updated_at":"2019-02-09T16:19:18.552Z","user_lists_id":2,"rating":"5"}]
```

I think you have not put sufficient data. Can you try by putting following data

```
u = User.create(:name => "another", :email => "ok@gmail.com")
l = List.create("This is list") // creating first
UserList.create(:user_id => 1, :list_id => 3,:rating => 5)
```

Please make sure you check ids and put proper ids in UserList. Note best practicing recomend ListUser name should be alphabet order for joining tables.

Comment: I think the difference is that you're using raw DB data, while they're using List objects, which I don't believe will ever allow them to access the rating even if the DB returns it as a column.

Comment: Could you explain more what you mean by List Objects? and any use case reference?

Comment: He has an active record model class, List. Instances of that I believe would only give access to fields that are part of his List model.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. so in my above code  `l = List.create` is also active record model class? and what is the exact difference between your mentioned List active record model class and mine? is it not the same thing?  I have also three classes active record classes and they are doing persistent saving to db.

Comment: I see that, but the data you posted is not an instance of the class, where did you get that data from?

Comment: I got data from `index` method which guy created at the beginning of the question. I used the same method to retrieve exactly what he was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can help you out again, I feel invested now ;)

I believe your issue here is that you're misunderstanding joins in the realm of active record. With active record queries, you are retrieving data for a specific model structure in the end, in this case that would be the List structure. The List structure can never contain data fields from another model, only its own.

Thus, the purpose of join is not to add data fields to your model, but to allow you to refine your results based on data from associated records in other tables. That is, if you wanted to only include List items that have a rating from a specific User greater than 3, you could use join to include the UserList table, and then use WHERE clauses to filter your results down to only those with a rating greater than 3. However your resulting List objects would only contain their own data, nothing from the UserList data. I don't believe there is any way to inject a field.

I think really what you should be doing is working off of the UserList model instead of the List model. The UserList model has the rating you're looking for, and you can always access the List directly off of the UserList because it has that direct one to one association. Going from a List to a UserList requires the extra input of which user you're looking for a UserList for, which complicates things.

A cool thing that you can do in active record that may be what you're looking for is delegate method handling to a relation. That is, you can tell UserLists to, instead of calling title on themselves and not coming up with anything, send it on to the correct List object and return the result. With this, you can delegate all the data fields for the List items, like `title` and what have you, in the UserList object and then the UserList object can basically behave as a wrapper around its List object. You do this by adding a line like this near the top of your model, probably best put after your associations:

```
class UserList < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :user

  # delegate the :title method to the :list relation above
  delegate :title, to: :list

  # a given user can only have one copy of a list item
  validates :list_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end
```

You can add as many fields to delegate as you want in a single call, so say there were also fields `year` and `director`, you could do `delegate :title, :year, :director, to: :list`

Perhaps a better thing if you truly do want the UserList to become a wrapper around the List objects is you can say `delegate_missing_to :list`, and then any methods that aren't defined on UserList will automatically try to go through the List. This way you can add new methods and fields to the List model and they'll automatically be delegated to in UserList.

Hopefully this helps, happy to clarify anything as needed!

Comment: Thanks @obermillerk. Sorry for responding so late!

Sorry to ask, but could you help connect the dots to the final output? Still learning and struggling...

My view (React) is expecting a JSON array `lists`, with keys e.g. `rating` (via the UserList model), `title` (via the List model), etc.

Comment: Sorry for all the edits -- forgot Stack Overflow doesn't allow code / line breaks in comments. Added my attempted code using the delegated "title" method of UserList above. Appreciate any help!